# Green tinted flickering screen with FFmpeg + v4l2loopback-dkms

Tags: ffmpeg, v4l2

I have a Raspberry PI 4 with a Raspberry 7" touch screen, where buster is installed with Ffmpeg, Gstreamer, and v4l2loopback-dkms.
To that I have attached a USB video grabber dongle, where I have a Pioneer rearcam attached.

Now my goal is to loopback `/dev/video0` to `/dev/video1`, but in that process my stream is getting a green tint, and it's flickering a lot.

Video0 is looking fine in VLC, so I guess it's my command that is wrong somehow.
I have tried various pix_fmt formats, but they more or less end up with the same result.

Can someone see what could be wrong please?

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -video_size "720x480" -i /dev/video0 -fv4l2 -pix_fmt yuv422 /dev/video1
```

[Video adapter output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qid0O.jpg)

Comment: Next time please copy and paste the text instead of making an image of the text.

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

- Input `-f` should be v4l2, not rawvideo.
- Output pixel format needs to be yuv420p, not yuv422p.